# Find volume between $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 2(y+z)$ and $ x^2+y^2 \le z^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Recently I've been proposed the next problem at my calculus course.

Find the volume of the following corps:
$$\left\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \; x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 2(y+z), \; x^2+y^2 \le z^2\right\}$$

On first place, I attempted to plot the functions via Mathematica.
This is a screenshot of the plot

[image]

I've thought to divide the figure in 4 shards like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0syKc.jpg) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhDeG.jpg), so I can find the volume of each one separately. (sorry for only having the images, I don't know how to explain it)

For the first part, I tried to find the intersection of the sphere ($x^2+y^2+z^2≤2(y+z)$) and the cone ($x^2+y^2 \le z^2$) and try to find a parabolic cylinder that goes trough that intersection and is normal to the XY plane, so I can have $y$ in function of $x$ so I'm able to do the integral, but I'm struggling here, so I hope you can help me.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Could you edit your post to show what you have tried?

Comment: It is bad, bad form to delete a question and repost it when we ask you questions or ask you to show some effort. Please do not do that again. We are not here to *do* your homework for you, and spamming us with posts is not going to change that. I asked you a question on your first post and you did not reply to it there or here. What is the section of your course in which this was assigned?

Comment: I don't know how to reply a comment so I write this here.
In first place, I'm sorry for deleting the previous post. The post automatically deleted the "Hi" I writed at the beginning, so I tried to reupload it to see if it worked.
In second place, it isn't my homework, it was a question that the teached proposed, but I didn't know how to say that (my english level is quite low).
Lastly, to answer your question, the section of the course was Multiple Variable Integration.

Comment: You previously asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4442238/), and deleted it after it was closed.  This is not appropriate behavoiur on Math SE, and is likely to lead the automatic systems to ban you from asking more questions.  When a question is closed, engage with the commenters, follow their advice, and *improve* that question so that it can be reopened.  Do *not* delete and repost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volume projection onto the $yz$-plane is the region enclosed by $z=y$ and $y^2+z^2=2(y+z)$, obtained by setting $x=0$. It is partitioned by the intersection projection of the two shapes, i.e. $z^2=(y+z)$. Then, convert to cylindrical coordinates with $(y,z)\to(r, \theta)$. The bounds are $\theta \in(\frac\pi4,\frac{3\pi}4)$, $r_s(\theta)= 2(\sin\theta +\cos\theta ) $ and the partition is $r_p(\theta)= \frac{\sin\theta +\cos\theta }{\sin^2\theta}$. The sphere and the core are respectively
$$x_s(r,\theta)=\sqrt{2r(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)-r^2} ,\>\>\>\>\>x_c(r,\theta)= r\sqrt{\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta} $$
and the volume integral is
\begin{align}
\int_{\frac\pi4}^{\frac{3\pi}4}& \int_0^{ r_p(\theta)}2x_c(r,\theta) rdrd\theta
+\int_{\frac\pi4}^{\frac{3\pi}4} \int_{r_p(\theta) }^{r_s(\theta )}
2x_s(r,\theta) rdrd\theta= \frac{7\pi}{12}+\frac{11\pi}{12}=\frac{3\pi}2
\end{align}
where the first integral is for the cone and the second for the sphere.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks a lot!